# Clojure Function Literals

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I am doing [Intro to Functions](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/14) problem, but I don't quite understand what is going on?  How are the 4 expressions below different?  If they are all the same, why have 4 different syntaxes?

```
(partial + 5)
#(+ % 5)
(fn [x] (+ x 5))
(fn add-five [x] (+ x 5))
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- `(fn [x] (+ x 5))` and `#(+ % 5)` - These two are completely equivalent, the latter just uses the [dispatch macro](http://clojure.org/reader) to make the code a little more concise. For short functions, the `#()` syntax is usually preferred and the `(fn [x])` syntax is better for functions which are a bit longer.  Also, if you have nested anonymous functions, you can't use `#()` for both because of the ambiguity this would cause.
- `(fn add-five [x] (+ x 5))` - is the same as the above two, except it has a name: add-five.  This can sometimes be useful, like if you need to make a recursive call to your function.*
- `(partial + 5)` - In clojure, `+` is a variadic function.  This means that it can accept any number of arguments.  `(+ 1 2)` and `(+ 1 2 3 4 5 6)` are both perfectly valid forms. `partial` is creating a new function which is identical to `+`, except that the first argument is always 5.  Because of this, `((partial + 5) 3 3 3)` is valid.  You could not use the other forms in this case.

*When making a recursive call from the tail position, you should use `recur`, however this is not always possible.